# Mongodb find() not working as expected, PHP

Tags: mongodb, php

Mongodb find() seems Not to work, I have tried all I could and nothing works so far. using PHP7+

I have a Document in the strure like the image below

[image]

In SQL I could do something like:`SELECT....... where 'common' LIKE '%Burk%'`

*The simple query is to call the countries collection and produce `Burkina Faso` as output*

> QUERY 1:

```
$countries_tb= $db->selectCollection('country_city_data');
 $countries = $countries_tb->find([],[
    'common' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Burk')]);
var_dump($countries);
```

the `var_dump` prints a list of all the countries in the database instead of getting only `Burkina Faso`

> QUERY 2:

when I do `find(without the empty [])`, it `var_dumps` nothing necessary

```
$countries = $countries_tb->find(/*without the []*/ [
    'common' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Burk')]);

var_dump($countries);
```

I get this:

[image]

**I have also tried this format.**

> QUERY 3:

```
 $countries = $countries_tb->find(
                     array('name'=>
 array(  'common'=>new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Burk'))));

                var_dump($countries);
```

Still no success.

As suggested by `@noobProgrammer` from SO below, doing like this:

```
$countries_tb->find(['name' => 
                  ['common'=>new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Burk')]], 
                  ['typeMap' => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']]);
```

**Produces this;**

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's cross-posted on SO

Comment: it was crossposted not in bad intention, i was looking for solutions, . i didnt know the best place to post. please have mercy

Comment: @ErickBest,Could you please show the command from which command you want to find the details.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan please see my Edit. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working finally!

This is what I did.

```
$countries = $countries_tb->find(array('name.common' =>   array('$regex' =>  'Burk') ) );
```

Notice the `.` in `name.common`

Here is my `foreach` loop'

```
foreach( $countries as $country => $name) { 

   foreach ($name as $n){

       if(isset($n->common)){

            var_dump($n->common);

        }

   }
}

//It prints out:    country_cities.php:90:string 'Burkina Faso' (length=12)
```

---

Somehow, this does NOT work

```
$countries = $countries_tb->find(
                         array('name'=>
                                 array('common' =>   
                                         array('$regex' =>   'Burk')) ) );
```

### This is the JSON'

```
{"_id":"55a0f42f20a4d760b5fc306d","altSpellings":["BF"],"area":272967,"borders":["BEN","CIV","GHA","MLI","NER","TGO"],"callingCode":["226"],"capital":"Ouagadougou","cca2":"BF","cca3":"BFA","ccn3":"854","cioc":"BUR","currency":["XOF"],"demonym":"Burkinabe","landlocked":true,"languages":{"fra":"French"},"latlng":[13,-2],"name":{"common":"Burkina Faso","native":{"fra":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"}},"official":"Burkina Faso"},"region":"Africa","subregion":"Western Africa","tld":[".bf"],"translations":{"cym":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"deu":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"fin":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"fra":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"hrv":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"ita":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"jpn":{"common":"ブルキナファソ","official":"ブルキナファソ"},"nld":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"por":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"rus":{"common":"Буркина-Фасо","official":"Буркина -Фасо"},"spa":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"}}}
```